# Rails does not write column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a totally strange problem:

Rails 6.0.0
ruby 2.5.7
mysql 8.0.15

it saves the most columns, but not all.
p.errors.full_messages delivers emtpy array and p.valid? delivers true.
but, p.to_geocode does not be set to true in the database, p.location_string is also not saved.
But, all the values, which are advised by the loop (hash.keys.each {..) are correctly stored.

what may there be?

thanks in advance!
Chris

Code:

```
  def write_project(hash)

    # MAKE RECORD

    p = Project.new
    hash.keys.each {|k| p[k.to_sym] = hash[k.to_sym]}
    p.created_by = session[:login_name]
    p.group = 'antenna_project'

    @default_values.each do |k, v|
      unless p[k.to_sym].present?
        p[k.to_sym] = v
      end
    end
    p.import_id = @import.id

    # ERROR HANDLING SAVE

    p[:to_geocode] = true
    p.location_string = [hash[:street].to_s, hash[:zip].to_s, hash[:city].to_s, 'switzerland'].reject(&:empty?).join(', ')
    unless p.save(validate: false)
      e = "COULD NOT SAVE RECORD"
      log_import_error(nil, e)
      return e
    end

    @import.block_others_until = (DateTime.now + 1.seconds)
    @import.save

    return "SUCCESS"
  end
```

Comment: Doesn't `p.save(validate: false)` prevent errors from being produced?

Comment: @Lee Whittaker: may be, but is'nt the case. if i step with debugger UNTIL the step `p.save(validate: false)`, before it is executed, and make `p.valid?`, result is `true`, but, after executing p.save, it doesnt store the values in the database